# Hello! I'm having trouble printing (Java)

Tags: java

The program is meant to modify the List items (defined at top), and there appears to be trouble printing the modified version to console.

Could I get some tips as to where (and perhaps what, for efficiency) to modify?

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Quiz4 {
    public static class ItemHolder{

        private List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<Integer> getItems(){
            return items;
        }

        public void addItems(Integer item){
            items.add(item);
        }

        public int size(){
            return items.size();
        }

        public String toString(){
            return items.toString();            
        }

        public void remove(Object obj) {
            items.remove(obj);  
        }   
        public boolean equals(int a, int b){
            boolean ret = false;
            if (a == b){
                ret = true;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        public int get(int index){
            return items.get(index);
        }
    }

    public static ItemHolder modify(ItemHolder items){
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ){
            if(items.get(i) == (items.get(i+1))){
                items.remove(items.get(i));
             }  
         }
         return items;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args){
        ItemHolder items = new ItemHolder();
        Scanner up = new Scanner(System.in);

        items.getItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter number. -1 to quit");
            String input = up.nextLine();
            int check = Integer.parseInt(input);
             if (check >= 0){
                items.addItems(check);
            }
            else{
            continue;
            }
        }
        modify(items);
        System.out.println(items);
        up.close();
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is printing code.

Comment: I just realized--printing is the focus of the question. I'll work to keep my questions from being so vague in the future.

Comment: _How_ is this not working? `System.out.println(items);` should print your items, given that `modify(items)` didn't remove them first. What happens when the program is run depends on the input given to it.

Comment: When the program runs, the console displays the content of the for loop in main, and then no prompt or output appears after that--console is stuck in endless loop (stop button required). This means the 'items' List isn't printed. Currently using a newer volume of eclipse, and this is imported code.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Modify method it will work

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size()-1;i++ ){
    if(items.get(i) == (items.get(i+1))){
        items.remove(items.get(i));
     }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The program is also outputting correctly.

Comment: @HeiwajimaSidekick22 you just forgetted `i++` in for loop ! :)